# How to get maximum date out of a date column which is in xml data using XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt

I have an intermediate XML document in application which looks like this

Sample Source XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <PositionMaster>
    <COL1>ticker</COL1>
    <COL2>asstClass</COL2>
    <COL3>orderId</COL3>
    <COL4>tradeDateTime</COL4>
    <COL5>entryDateTime</COL5>
    <COL6>settlementDate</COL6>
    <COL7>securityName</COL7>
    <COL8>commission</COL8>
    <COL9>clearingFee</COL9>
    <COL10>exchangeFees</COL10>
    <COL11>exchangeRateTrade</COL11>    
  </PositionMaster>
  <PositionMaster>
    <COL1>AC</COL1>
    <COL2>Equity</COL2>
    <COL3></COL3>
    <COL4>10/19/2023</COL4>
    <COL5>05/30/2023  16:00</COL5>
    <COL6>06-01-2023</COL6>
    <COL7></COL7>
    <COL8>3.38</COL8>
    <COL9>0.29</COL9>
    <COL10>*</COL10>
    <COL11>*</COL11>    
  </PositionMaster>
  <PositionMaster>
    <COL1>AD</COL1>
    <COL2>Equity</COL2>
    <COL3></COL3>
    <COL4>10/20/2023</COL4>
    <COL5>05/30/2023  16:00</COL5>
    <COL6>06-01-2023</COL6>
    <COL7></COL7>
    <COL8>12.36</COL8>
    <COL9>7.37</COL9>
    <COL10>*</COL10>
    <COL11>*</COL11>    
  </PositionMaster>
  <PositionMaster>
    <COL1>AM</COL1>
    <COL2>Equity</COL2>
    <COL3></COL3>
    <COL4>10/20/2023</COL4>
    <COL5>05/30/2023  16:00</COL5>
    <COL6>06-01-2023</COL6>
    <COL7></COL7>
    <COL8>8.44</COL8>
    <COL9>6.55</COL9>
    <COL10>*</COL10>
    <COL11>*</COL11>    
  </PositionMaster>  
</DocumentElement>
```

Buy by using the xslt1.0 like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:my6="put-your-namespace-uri-here"
  xmlns:my2="put-your-namespace-uri-here">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentElement>

      <xsl:for-each select="//PositionMaster">

        <xsl:variable name="startDate">
          <xsl:for-each select="//PositionMaster/COL4">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

    

        <!--<xsl:variable name="startDate" select="string(COL4[not(. >COL4)])" />-->



        <xsl:variable name="Processdate">
          <xsl:value-of select="COL4"/>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:variable name="varFinalDateCheck">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$startDate = $Processdate">
              <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:if test="number($varNetPosition)">

          <PositionMaster>


            <xsl:variable name="PB_NAME">
              <xsl:value-of select="''" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="PB_SYMBOL_NAME">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL7" />
            </xsl:variable>

         

            <xsl:variable name="varSEDOL">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL23" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <Symbol>
              <xsl:value-of select="COL23" />
            </Symbol>

           

            <xsl:variable name="PB_FUND_NAME" select="COL21" />


            <AccountName>
              <xsl:value-of select="$PB_FUND_NAME" />
            </AccountName>

            <xsl:variable name="Side" select="normalize-space(COL15)"/>

            <SideTagValue>
              <xsl:value-of select="COL27" />
            </SideTagValue>

            <!--<xsl:variable name="maxDate">
              <xsl:call-template name="updateMaxDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="date"  select="COL4"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>-->

            <!--<xsl:for-each select="//COL4">
              -->
            <!-- Call the template to update the maximum date -->
            <!--
              <xsl:call-template name="updateMaxDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="." />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>-->


            <PositionStartDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="$startDate" />
            </PositionStartDate>

            <xsl:variable name="varSettlementDate">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL6" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <PositionSettlementDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="$varSettlementDate"/>
            </PositionSettlementDate>


          </PositionMaster>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DocumentElement>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is select the all date date from this xslm.
i need to pick the only max date data from this xslm.

```
Buy by using the xslt1.0 like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:my6="put-your-namespace-uri-here"
  xmlns:my2="put-your-namespace-uri-here">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentElement>

      <xsl:for-each select="//PositionMaster">

        <xsl:variable name="startDate">
          <xsl:for-each select="//PositionMaster/COL4">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

    

        <!--<xsl:variable name="startDate" select="string(COL4[not(. >COL4)])" />-->



        <xsl:variable name="Processdate">
          <xsl:value-of select="COL4"/>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:variable name="varFinalDateCheck">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$startDate = $Processdate">
              <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:if test="number($varNetPosition)">

          <PositionMaster>


            <xsl:variable name="PB_NAME">
              <xsl:value-of select="''" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="PB_SYMBOL_NAME">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL7" />
            </xsl:variable>

         

            <xsl:variable name="varSEDOL">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL23" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <Symbol>
              <xsl:value-of select="COL23" />
            </Symbol>

           

            <xsl:variable name="PB_FUND_NAME" select="COL21" />


            <AccountName>
              <xsl:value-of select="$PB_FUND_NAME" />
            </AccountName>

            <xsl:variable name="Side" select="normalize-space(COL15)"/>

            <SideTagValue>
              <xsl:value-of select="COL27" />
            </SideTagValue>

            <!--<xsl:variable name="maxDate">
              <xsl:call-template name="updateMaxDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="date"  select="COL4"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>-->

            <!--<xsl:for-each select="//COL4">
              -->
            <!-- Call the template to update the maximum date -->
            <!--
              <xsl:call-template name="updateMaxDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="." />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>-->


            <PositionStartDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="$startDate" />
            </PositionStartDate>

            <xsl:variable name="varSettlementDate">
              <xsl:value-of select="COL6" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <PositionSettlementDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="$varSettlementDate"/>
            </PositionSettlementDate>


          </PositionMaster>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DocumentElement>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

which is select the all date date from this xslm.i need to pick the only max date data from this xslm.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest date from `COL4` you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
    <max-date>
        <xsl:for-each select="PositionMaster">
            <!-- sort by year -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(COL4, 7, 4)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <!-- sort by month -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(COL4, 1, 2)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <!-- sort by day -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(COL4, 4, 2)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="COL4"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </max-date>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it not working .

Comment: Well, it works for me and using your XML as the input I get `<max-date>10/20/2023</max-date>` as the output. I don't know what you're doing and "it not working" is not a good description.

Comment: i need to get the 10/20/2023 . not <max-date>10/20/2023</max-date>
so that i can compare the date and fillter the data for max date.

Comment: could you please suggest any template in xslt  to get the desired output.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="maxDate">
        <xsl:for-each select="//PositionMaster">
          <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(COL4, 7, 4), substring(COL4, 1, 2), substring(COL4, 4, 2))" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="COL4" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

i am using this code in xslt . but it still not generating the correct out put.
Can you pleaes suggest come solution heres

Comment: Well, you have one instance of COL4 that does not contain a date. So either exclude it from the selection or change the sort type to number.